# `strip` Environment Does Not Work in Empty Document / Interaction with `\afterpage`

Tags: floats, two-column, afterpage, cuted

I have a question about the interaction of the packages [`afterpage`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) and [`cuted`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cuted) in two-column mode near the document end - or about `cuted`'s  `strip` environment in otherwise empty documents for that matter.

[`afterpage`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) offers the command `\afterpage` which allows me to execute some code on the next page.
[`cuted`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cuted) offers the environment `strip` which can temporarily switch from two-column to one-column mode.

It seems to me that if I use `\afterpage` to delay the layout of a `strip` environment, in some cases, this environment is not laid out at all. In particular, this seems to happen near the end of a document.

I believe that this is caused by an issue in `cuted`: `strip` environments may not get laid out if they appear in otherwise empty documents.

*I would like to know how to fix this*, i.e., how to obtain the expected behavior: the `strip` being laid out properly on the next (i.e., last) page of the document. (I need that for the [`figureSeries`](https://github.com/thomasWeise/figureSeries) package I am working on).

In the following, I will present several MWEs exhibiting different behaviors, which may help to solve this question.

### 1. The Problem Case

`\afterpage` is used as only command in the document. It contains a `strip` environment. Executing this program with `pdflatex` will not produce any output document.

#### 1.1. The MWE Code

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}%
\usepackage{cuted}%
\usepackage{afterpage}%
\begin{document}%
\afterpage{%
\begin{strip}%
A B C%
\end{strip}%
}%
\end{document}%
```

#### 1.2. The Log File Produced by `pdflatex`

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) (format=pdflatex 2015.5.1)  13 JUL 2015 08:48
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty
Package: lipsum 2011/04/14 v1.2 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
\c@lips@count=\count87
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sttools/cuted.sty
Package: cuted 2012/10/04 v1.5 Mixing onecolumn and twocolumn modes
\At@ViperColsBreak=\toks14
\v@aaa=\box26
\v@ccc=\box27
\lastskip@a=\skip43
\lastskip@b=\skip44
\lastskip@d=\skip45
\lastbox@a=\box28
\stripsep=\skip46
\@viper=\box29
\viper@penalty=\count88
\hold@viper=\box30
\ht@viper=\dimen103
) (./afterpage.sty
Package: afterpage 2014/10/28 v1.08 After-Page Package (DPC)
\AP@output=\toks15
\AP@partial=\box31
\AP@footins=\box32
)
(./test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
Extra height:0.0pt when 0.0pt
(2)Left:0.0pt Right:0.0pt Output:0.0pt
- LAST -
Left:0.0pt
Right:0.0pt
Output:0.0pt
 (./test.aux) )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 435 strings out of 493304
 5019 string characters out of 6139872
 144451 words of memory out of 5000000
 3970 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 957 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,4n,19p,151b,52s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

No pages of output.
PDF statistics:
 0 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

### 2. Without `strip`, `afterpage` Works Near the Document End

The error is definitely related to the `strip` environment from `cuted` in conjunction with `\afterpage`, because without `strip`, `\afterpage`ing something in an otherwise blank document works and produces one page of output.

#### 2.1. The MWE Code (without `strip`)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}%
\usepackage{afterpage}%
\begin{document}%
\afterpage{%
A B C%
}%
\end{document}%
```

### 3. The Problem Case without `\afterpage`

Interestingly, having a `strip` environment in a blank document also produces no output either.

#### 3.1. The MWE Code (without `\afterpage`)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}%
\usepackage{cuted}%
\begin{document}%
\begin{strip}%
A B C
\end{strip}%
\end{document}%
```

#### 3.2. The Log File Produced by `pdflatex`

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) (format=pdflatex 2015.5.1)  13 JUL 2015 09:36
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sttools/cuted.sty
Package: cuted 2012/10/04 v1.5 Mixing onecolumn and twocolumn modes
\At@ViperColsBreak=\toks14
\v@aaa=\box26
\v@ccc=\box27
\lastskip@a=\skip43
\lastskip@b=\skip44
\lastskip@d=\skip45
\lastbox@a=\box28
\stripsep=\skip46
\@viper=\box29
\viper@penalty=\count87
\hold@viper=\box30
\ht@viper=\dimen103
) (./test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
Extra height:0.0pt when 0.0pt
(2)Left:0.0pt Right:0.0pt Output:0.0pt
- LAST -
Left:0.0pt
Right:0.0pt
Output:0.0pt

(./test.aux) )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 237 strings out of 493304
 2693 string characters out of 6139872
 52430 words of memory out of 5000000
 3779 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 957 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,4n,19p,150b,46s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

No pages of output.
PDF statistics:
 0 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

### 4. The Problem Case + `\clearpage`

I thought this can maybe be solved by adding a `\clearpage` at the end of the document, but to no avail:

#### 4.1. The MWE Code (with `\clearpage`)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}%
\usepackage{cuted}%
\usepackage{afterpage}%
\begin{document}%
\afterpage{%
\begin{strip}%
A B C%
\end{strip}%
}%
\clearpage%
\end{document}%
```

#### 4.2. The Log File Produced by `pdflatex`

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) (format=pdflatex 2015.5.1)  13 JUL 2015 08:50
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty
Package: lipsum 2011/04/14 v1.2 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
\c@lips@count=\count87
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sttools/cuted.sty
Package: cuted 2012/10/04 v1.5 Mixing onecolumn and twocolumn modes
\At@ViperColsBreak=\toks14
\v@aaa=\box26
\v@ccc=\box27
\lastskip@a=\skip43
\lastskip@b=\skip44
\lastskip@d=\skip45
\lastbox@a=\box28
\stripsep=\skip46
\@viper=\box29
\viper@penalty=\count88
\hold@viper=\box30
\ht@viper=\dimen103
) (./afterpage.sty
Package: afterpage 2014/10/28 v1.08 After-Page Package (DPC)
\AP@output=\toks15
\AP@partial=\box31
\AP@footins=\box32
)
(./test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
Extra height:0.0pt when 0.0pt
(2)Left:0.0pt Right:0.0pt Output:0.0pt
- LAST -
Left:0.0pt
Right:0.0pt
Output:0.0pt
 (./test.aux) )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 435 strings out of 493304
 5019 string characters out of 6139872
 144451 words of memory out of 5000000
 3970 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 957 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,4n,19p,151b,52s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

No pages of output.
PDF statistics:
 0 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

### 5. The Problem Case + `\strut\clearpage`

Interestingly, if I add a `\strut` before the `\clearpage`, I get an `! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.`:

#### 5.1. The MWE Code + `\strut\clearpage`

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}%
\usepackage{cuted}%
\usepackage{afterpage}%
\begin{document}%
\afterpage{%
\begin{strip}%
A B C%
\end{strip}%
}%
\strut\clearpage%
\end{document}%
```

#### 5.2. The Log File Produced by `pdflatex`

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) (format=pdflatex 2015.5.1)  13 JUL 2015 09:37
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sttools/cuted.sty
Package: cuted 2012/10/04 v1.5 Mixing onecolumn and twocolumn modes
\At@ViperColsBreak=\toks14
\v@aaa=\box26
\v@ccc=\box27
\lastskip@a=\skip43
\lastskip@b=\skip44
\lastskip@d=\skip45
\lastbox@a=\box28
\stripsep=\skip46
\@viper=\box29
\viper@penalty=\count87
\hold@viper=\box30
\ht@viper=\dimen103
) (./afterpage.sty
Package: afterpage 2014/10/28 v1.08 After-Page Package (DPC)
\AP@output=\toks15
\AP@partial=\box31
\AP@footins=\box32
)
(./test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.


! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.10 \strut\clearpage
                     %
? x

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 255 strings out of 493304
 3012 string characters out of 6139872
 52890 words of memory out of 5000000
 3795 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 957 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,1n,19p,150b,36s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
PDF statistics:
 0 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

### 6. Reasons

I need to figure out how to get this work for my [`figureSeries`](https://github.com/thomasWeise/figureSeries) package.

This question is related to [Float(s) lost: Problem (Possible) from afterpage + double-column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252487): I use the `strip` environment from `cuted` as a replacement of my old layout routine for which I could not get the `Float(s) lost` to disappear.

Comment: I'm not surprised that `afterpage` and `cuted` are conflicting, because both try to change the output routine. My impression is that you simply want to use `figure*` that will insert the material as a two column object at the top of the next page.

Comment: I'm not surprised either, but I have little other options (and my LaTeX is much weaker than either Prof. Carlisle's or Prof. Tolušis') ^_^ ... Anyway, Prof. Tolušis sent me a quick fix suggestion via email. In my case, it seems to work. Once he has verified it deeper with his package, he may either choose to post it here (or I will do it for him later).

Comment: No, I want more: My (now much better working) `figureSeries` allows you to have something like a page-breaking `figure*` working both in one- and two-column documents. It can contain arbitrarily many sub-figures. If you have more sub-figures than what fits on a page, it will break over to the next page. This is needed because I programmatically generate LaTeX documents and don't know the number of sub-figures in advance (and I do not want to replicate LaTeX's layout engine in my program to determine how to break the figure series automatically into several `figure*`s automatically).